# Can't send POST request to Google Apps Script

Tags: http, google-apps-script

I'm trying to deploy a Google Apps Script as a web app, but while I have no problem doing GET requests, I'm having trouble with POST requests.

My code is very simple:

```
function doGet(request) {
    var result = JSON.stringify({ data: 'Thanks, I received the GET request' });
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(result).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}

function doPost(request) {
    var result = JSON.stringify({ data: 'Thanks, I received the POST request' });
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(result).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

I deployed the web app with "Execute the app as: Me" and "Who has access to the app: Anyone, even anonymous". Every time I do some change I re-deploy it with a new version ("Project version: New").

After publishing, my curl GET request works perfectly:

```sh
> curl -L https://script.google.com/macros/s/$SCRIPT_ID/exec
{"data":"Thanks, I received the GET request"}
```

However, my POST request (`curl -L -XPOST https://script.google.com/macros/s/$SCRIPT_ID/exec`) just shows me a generic Google HTML page saying "Sorry, unable to open the file at this time. Please check the address and try again".

I tried sending some data and providing a content type, but nothing changed. I also tried changing the output type to just `ContentService.createTextOutput("OK")`, but it didn't work either. Curiously, deleting `doPost` changes the error message to "Script function not found: doPost" as expected. If it makes any difference, this script is attached to a Google spreadsheet.

Are there any special permissions I need to give to the script for POST requests specifically?

Comment: In the case which uses POST method for Web Apps, when the curl command is used with `-XPOST`, such error occurs. In this case, POST method is run using `-d ""` instead of `-XPOST`. Namely, please test `curl -L -d "" https://script.google.com/macros/s/$SCRIPT_ID/exec` . The request body is the same between `-XPOST` and `-d ""`. But the result is different. If this didn't resolve your issue. I apologize.

Comment: This solved the issue! And today I learned one new thing: even though curl helpfully says "Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred" when I do a request with `-XPOST` and a payload, its behavior is different in the presence of redirects. `-XPOST` forces all subsequent requests after a redirect to be made using `POST`. On the other hand, if we don't specify `-XPOST`, subsequent requests after the first `POST` are made as `GET` requests. I don't know if this is intended behavior, but it's certainly unintuitive. Thank you for the help, Tanaike!

Comment: Done. Thanks again!

Comment: Thank you for your response. I upvote it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that the problem was with my usage of curl, on subtle differences between using `-XPOST` and not using it. As suggested by Tanaike, changing from:

```sh
curl -L -XPOST https://script.google.com/macros/s/$SCRIPT_ID/exec
```

to

```sh
curl -L -d '' https://script.google.com/macros/s/$SCRIPT_ID/exec
```

Solved the issue. Even though curl helpfully says "Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred" when I do a request with `-XPOST` and a payload, its behavior is different in the presence of redirects. `-XPOST` forces all subsequent requests after a redirect to be made using POST as a method. On the other hand, if I don't specify `-XPOST`, the requests after the first POST are made as GET requests. I don't know if this is curl's intended behavior, but it's certainly unintuitive.